# update specific field in text file in specific line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

Below is a code that I'm able to update the quantity of my book. But I cant seem to make it so that I can update my other things like book name, author, price etc.
Heres the code:

```
if grep -q "^$bookname:$author:" BookDB.txt
   then 
   read -p "Update Qty to what?" newQty 
   sed -i "s/^\($bookname:$author:[^:]*\):[^:]*:/\1:$newQty:/" BookDB.txt 
   echo "Book's Qty has been updated successfully!" 
   else 
   echo "$0: BookDB.Txt: no '$title' by '$author'" >&2 
   fi
```

My database would be like this:

```
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince:J.K Rowling:40.30:10:50
The little Red Riding Hood:Dan Lin:40.80:20:10
Harry Potter - The Phoniex:J.K Rowling:50.00:30:20
Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow:Dan Lin:55.00:33:790
Little Prince:The Prince:15.00:188:9
Lord of The Ring:Johnny Dept:56.80:100:38
Three Little Pig:Andrew Lim:89.10:290:189
All About Ubuntu:Ubuntu Team:76.00:55:133
Catch Me If You Can:Mary Ann:23.60:6:2
Happy Day:Mary Ann:12.99:197:101
haha:gaga:1:10:1
```

So how could i change certain fields like when i select the book name Lord of the ring author johnny Dept i can change the book name to maybe lord of the kings?

```
Lord of The King:Johnny Dept:56.80:100:38
```

Comment: You should consider using an appropriate language for something like this. I don't think that a shell is the right tool! For example manipulation of `csv` files is really easy and legible with `python` or `perl`...

Comment: An unordered csv file can hardly be called a "database".  At the very least, you need to put the entries in some usable order before you can use the word "database".

Answer (score 1):

Like **user1146332**, I also suggest to switch to a more powerful language. Here an example using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). It uses module `Getopt::Long` to read arguments and loops through the file for a matching line.

It seems to work but it's up to you to do a better checking of errors, for example, that both `book` and `author` variables are defined before using them in the regular expression.

One more thing, I use `split()` with a colon to extract fields, I don't know how you handle a book with a colon in its name but in that case you will need an additional module to parse CSV, like `Text::CSV` or fight harder with a better `split` expression.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my ($book, $author, $newbook, $quantity);

my $r = GetOptions(
        q|book=s| => \$book,
        q|author=s| => \$author,
        q|newbook=s| => \$newbook,
        q|quantity=i| => \$quantity,
) or die;

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die;

while ( <$fh> ) { 
        chomp;
        my @f = split /:/;
        next if @f < 5;
        if ( $f[0] =~ m/(?i)\Q$book\E/ &&
             $f[1] =~ m/(?i)\Q$author\E/ ) { 
                $f[0] = defined $newbook ? $newbook : $f[0];
                $f[3] = defined $quantity ? $quantity : $f[3];
                printf qq|%s\n|, join q|:|, @f; 
                next;
        }   

        printf qq|%s\n|, $_; 
}
```

An example with:

```
perl script.pl --book="lord of the ring" --author=dep --newbook="Lord of the King" --quantity=99 infile
```

Yields:

```
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince:J.K Rowling:40.30:10:50
The little Red Riding Hood:Dan Lin:40.80:20:10
Harry Potter - The Phoniex:J.K Rowling:50.00:30:20
Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow:Dan Lin:55.00:33:790
Little Prince:The Prince:15.00:188:9
Lord of the King:Johnny Dept:56.80:99:38
Three Little Pig:Andrew Lim:89.10:290:189
All About Ubuntu:Ubuntu Team:76.00:55:133
Catch Me If You Can:Mary Ann:23.60:6:2
Happy Day:Mary Ann:12.99:197:101
haha:gaga:1:10:1
```

Answer (score 1):

What about [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)?

```
sed 's/\bLord of The Ring\b/Lord of The King/' file
```

---

```
$ cat file
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince:J.K Rowling:40.30:10:50
The little Red Riding Hood:Dan Lin:40.80:20:10
Harry Potter - The Phoniex:J.K Rowling:50.00:30:20
Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow:Dan Lin:55.00:33:790
Little Prince:The Prince:15.00:188:9
Lord of The Ring:Johnny Dept:56.80:100:38
Three Little Pig:Andrew Lim:89.10:290:189
All About Ubuntu:Ubuntu Team:76.00:55:133
Catch Me If You Can:Mary Ann:23.60:6:2
Happy Day:Mary Ann:12.99:197:101
haha:gaga:1:10:1

$ sed 's/\bLord of The Ring\b/Lord of The King/' file
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince:J.K Rowling:40.30:10:50
The little Red Riding Hood:Dan Lin:40.80:20:10
Harry Potter - The Phoniex:J.K Rowling:50.00:30:20
Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow:Dan Lin:55.00:33:790
Little Prince:The Prince:15.00:188:9
Lord of The King:Johnny Dept:56.80:100:38
Three Little Pig:Andrew Lim:89.10:290:189
All About Ubuntu:Ubuntu Team:76.00:55:133
Catch Me If You Can:Mary Ann:23.60:6:2
Happy Day:Mary Ann:12.99:197:101
haha:gaga:1:10:1
```

Send the output with redirection `>` to a new file or use sed's `-i` option for *in place editing*.

- redirection

  ```
  sed 's/\bLord of The Ring\b/Lord of The King/' file>newfile
  ```
- *in place etit* with `.bak` file

  ```
  sed -i.bak 's/\bLord of The Ring\b/Lord of The King/' file
  ```